# AutoHotKey v1 Send Each Keystroke to Multiple Chrome Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, multibox

I have the following script which is meant to immediately forward any key that the user presses to all Chrome tabs (focused or unfocused) which have the webpage title matching tabTitleA and tabTitleB.

I have tried numerous alternatives and looked on their community forums and on here but was unable to get it to work.  It fails to send the keystrokes to both web browser tabs.  In my case, these tabs are both opened in different Chrome windows and both webpages are visible on the screen.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force

; IMPORTANT: THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS," WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED. 
; IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES, OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT, OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF, OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. 
; USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. THE AUTHOR IS NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DATA LOSS, HARDWARE DAMAGE, OR OTHER CONSEQUENCES ARISING FROM THE USE OF THE SOFTWARE.

;In this script, each key is separately hooked as a hotkey, and when you press a key (e.g., "a"), it sends itself to all matching Chrome tabs, both focused and unfocused. You can repeat this pattern for other keys as needed. 

; Function to send keys to matching tabs
SendKeysToMatchingTabs(keys) {
    ; Loop through all open Chrome windows and tabs
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ; Use partial title matching
    
    WinGet, windows, List, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Loop % windows.MaxIndex()
    {
        windowTitle := windows[A_Index]
        
        ; Check if the title matches either target title
        if (windowTitle ~= "tabTitleA" || windowTitle ~= "tabTitleB") {
            ; Activate the matching tab (window)
            WinActivate, % "ahk_id " windows[A_Index]
            
            ; Send the keys to the activated tab (window)
            SendInput, % keys
        }
    }
}

; Hook all keys to send to matching tabs
#IfWinActive  ; This applies to all windows

~*::SendKeysToMatchingTabs(A_ThisHotkey)

; Function to update the list of matching tabs (not needed in this version)
; UpdateMatchingTabs() {
; }

; Initial update of matching tabs (not needed in this version)
; UpdateMatchingTabs()

; ExitApp is not necessary in this version
; ExitApp
```

Any helpful advise or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: These different tabs, are they going to the same domain? By default Chrome makes a process per tab unless the tabs are from the same domain. If you want to have a per-tab process you could apply `--process-per-tab` on the startup properties.

Comment: Both tabs are going to the same domain, but they are in separate chrome windows.